# Detecting Chinese Characters in Redshift

Tags: regex, posix, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, I'm trying to detect text with at least one Chinese character in it. I've tried the following in redshift (it uses POSIX):

```
SELECT regexp_instr('你好', '[\p{Han}]');
SELECT regexp_instr('你好', '[\u4e00-\u9fff]');
```

but all of these return `0` (they should return `1`). I must be doing something silly?

Comment: If it is POSIX then you can't use those `\p` and `\u` notations. They do not mean anything special between brackets.

Comment: @revo: Is there a POSIX equivalent?

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Comment: can you access/use plpythonu UDF's? (you may need an admin to give you access)

Answer (score -1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/qDQBRZ/1/) might help you to design a regex for any language:

```
\pL
```

[image]